# Creating api or shareable library on ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have my ros2 workspace on my device but when I send that device all my code is viewable and can be copied. I am trying to make my workspace private by making it a shareable library or .so files or by creating an API file. Not sure if that's the right way or even a way to do that or if it's a better way that can satisfy my needs.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402661/creating-api-or-shareable-library-on-ros2/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could (1) distribute binaries (2) ship the robot with just the `install` space (there's no need to give them a workspace) or (3) use Snaps

But there are far more options than just those, just some of the ones on top of mind

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-06-22**:
Thanks for the reply,
Most of the packages are in python and if I just ship with install it contains all my code. This doesn't happen with CPP files or packages.
Is it possible for you to provide some resources that you used?
Thanks again.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-06-22**:
There are code obfuscation tools for Python, but I don't specifically have experience with them, I assumed this referred to C++ since you refer to .so files.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-06-24**:
Thank you will do more digging.